# determine node of a partition in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cassandra-3.0

This is maybe a special question but is it possible to determine the node(s) of a partion key?

example: I have a partition key id (int) and I'm using the default [Partitioner](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architecturePartitionerM3P_c.html)(Murmur3Partitioner) with 3 nodes and replication factor "1". Can I determine the one node with id = 3?

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
    id int,    
    content text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, content)
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `nodetool getendpoints <keyspace> <table> <partition_key>`

or you can use `select token(<partition_key>) from <table_name>`  and then run `nodetool ring`.

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669991/how-does-cassandra-find-the-node-that-contains-the-data) for further info