# How to determine cassandra partition for a given PK on the client?

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying Cassandra to replace mysql at a large dataset I have (2.5Tb/5 billion rows) that I can't scale more in a single server.

I insert/update a few million rows every hour. Currently, I'm inserting and querying one by one in cassandra because I don't know which partition has the data, and grouping them seem to be slower. But one by one, I can't match the speed of a single mysql server even with 3 cassandra nodes.

In mysql, I can batch because I know it stores all in the same server. Is it possible, using the value of the primary key, to determine the partition on client side, so I can group the queries more effectively with BATCH or SELECT..IN?

I mean, given a group of PKs like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ... and N servers, i'd like to know that say, rows 1 3, 5 are in the same partition, so I can group then in my queries. Is this possible with cassandra?

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928762/determine-node-of-a-partition-in-cassandra/) helps

Comment: @Horia I don't think so, because this depends on the nodetool or an instance, and that would kill the performance. What I need is more the algorithm or some way for the driver itself do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're performing queries with `WHERE` on partition key, then most of time drivers take care of most effective routing of data to replicas that have this data (only if you didn't change [load balancing policy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/load_balancing/) - by default all drivers use so-called `TokenAware` policy) by calculating token for given partition key, and find replica(s) for it.

If you need to fetch multiple entries, then running N queries in parallel via async API & merging results on client side will be more effective than performing query with `IN`.

P.S. In Cassandra `BATCH` has slightly different semantic than in relational databases. Please check [this documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchTOC.html) for recommended patterns.

Comment: I didn't mark this before, but thanks. That is right. My problem was that I was connecting to the cluster through NAT. After enabling debug on the driver, I could see it was trying to connect to the other instances through their private addresses and couldn't, so it was routing everything through the same instance. After adding a translation to the driver, it connected to all instances and routed properly directly to each instance. I ended up using a simple select with prepared statement and it was much faster than the IN clause.