# How to make sure that data is replicated n no of times in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, cqlsh

If say RF = 3, in a 5 nodes single data center, then how can I see where exactly my data lands in which node for any keyspace.tablename, and how to prove that data is exactly replicated on 3 nodes.

I have tried various nodetool commands but none give me the exact result or what I am trying to see.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669991/how-does-cassandra-find-the-node-that-contains-the-data

Comment: This link does not explain or confirm the RF and on which nodes the data is exactly saved.

Comment: bring the node down on which it says data is there... and then query for same data... you will still get data

Answer (score 3):

You can prove this using Inserts and queries with various Consistency Levels (CL) from the client side (`cqlsh` for instance). I'll explain:

1. Create the Keyspace with RF=3 -> Create the table
2. `INSERT` data with `CL=ALL` (this means all 3 replicas must ACK that the write was successful)
3. While all nodes are up query (`SELECT`) for the data using `CL=ALL` (all 3 replicas must send response for the query to be considered successful)
4. Stop C* on 1 of the nodes
5. While 1 node is down (`DN` state in `nodetool status`) query (`SELECT`) for the data using `CL=ALL` (all 3 replicas must send response for the query to be considered successful).

   a. If the query succeeds, than all 3 replicas are still up and you need to stop another C* node.

   b. If the query fails, set the CL to `CL=QUORUM` (only 2 out of 3 replicas must send response for the query to be considered successful), and execute the query again.

you can continue this sequence with `CL=ONE` and even `CL=ANY`.

You can read more about `cqlsh` and how to modify the CL [here](http://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/cqlsh/#special-commands)