# How cassandra guarantees that a key goes to different nodes when building the different ring nodes?

Tags: cassandra, replication, sharding, consistent-hashing

If I understand correctly, Cassandra "builds" N ring nodes where N is the replication factor.

From [cassandra docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/architecture/dynamo.html#consistent-hashing-using-a-token-ring)

[image: cassandra rings]

How cassandra achieves this while guaranteeing that a key always corresponds to different nodes in each ring?
I'm asking this because I want to implement something similar for the [ConsistentHashPartitioningService](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/finagle-20.8.1/finagle-partitioning/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/partitioning/ConsistentHashPartitioningService.scala) in finagle.

If someone can point to me to the code where this happens so I can start trying to figure it out that would be incredible helpful.

Comment: After reading this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669991/how-does-cassandra-find-the-node-that-contains-the-data and taking another look the image I guess it just picks the next X nodes, where X is the replication factor.